# $(document).on("click") not working but $('selector').on("click") works why?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working with `video.js` and `video.js` library is loading via script tag I want to track click function on list item and update player-menu.

```
$(".vjs-menu-item").on("click" ,function(){ alert('selector');});
```

but not working this one

```
$(document).on("click",".vjs-menu-item", function() {alert('document'); });
```

Hence `$(document)` method only works on these items which added on same page i.e

```
<p id="vjs-menu-item"> click me </p>
```

Comment: how about change `$(document) to $("html, body")`

Comment: @bugscoder this should be same as document behave only works on elements on same page but not working on dynamically loaded elements (vidoejs  controls) .

Comment: Avoid using ID selectors in dynamic content at all. Browsers use a fast lookup cache that can only access the first match. Use classes and class selectors instead. At the moment you have a mix of IDs in HTML but a class selector.

Answer (score 4):

Here the selector is `id` but you are referencing to a  `class`

Change to this

```
$(document).on("click","#vjs-menu-item", function() {alert('documnet'); });
```

or use `class` instead of id in `html`

**HTML**

```
<p class="vjs-menu-item">Click me</p>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).on("click",".vjs-menu-item", function() {
    alert('document');
});
```

Comment: i try it but as i say it works only those element which load in same page not working on those which loaded dynamically via library :(

Comment: Using a class instead is the correct advice. A delegated event handler is generally a bad choice for IDs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#vjs-menu-item").click(function(){
    alert('document');
  });
});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rushil_pachchigar/kj913usm/)

Comment: means? As per your question its working you can check jsfiddle as well?

Comment: this is same as 
$(".vjs-menu-item").on("click" ,function(){ alert('selector');});

Comment: Should not be using IDs and ID selectors at all in dynamically loaded content. That is generally a mistake and classes should be used instead. That means it is the HTML and not the code that is at fault here.